# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name views, locale en

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I have a file called `views.properties` inside my `src/main/webapp` folder. and I have the following line inside my `court-servlet.xml` file. The `court-servlet.xml` is located in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder.

```
<bean id="resourceBundleResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="basename" value="views" />
    <property name="order" value="#{contentNegotiatingResolver.order+1}" />
</bean>
```

However, I keep getting exception whenever I launch the app. It keeps throwing exception

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name views, locale en
java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:952)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.getBundle(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:271)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.initFactory(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:225)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver.loadView(ResourceBundleViewResolver.java:194)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.resolveViewName(ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.java:357)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1091)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Can someone please help me solving this issue? I tried some solutions posted here before, but none of them works.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested it with views_en.properties??

Comment: Yes, I did. I tested it with views_en.properties with <property name="basename" value="views" /> and <property name="basename" value="views_en" />. None of them works. So I switched it back.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution to this problem. The `views.properties` file needs to be placed inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

Based on your answer, your are missing to put `views.properties` file in `class path`. Make sure to put it the `class path`. You don't need to put under `WEB-INF/classes` directory directly.

Rename `views.properties` to `views_en.properties`. You have to configure the `properties` configuration with `name + _ +  locale`. But, It is not for all situation.